# What's the difference between Gregory Mankiw's "Macroeconomics" 4th ed. and 10th ed.?

Tags: macroeconomics, self-study, books

I am planning to use Gregory Mankiw's [*Macroeconomics*](https://store.macmillanlearning.com/us/product/Macroeconomics/p/1319105998) (not to be confused with his *Principles of Economics*) for self-studying macroeconomics, along with David Weil's [*Economic Growth*](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1138568449). As you can see, Greg Mankiw's macroeconomics textbook is currently in its tenth edition. However, the only copy I have is of the [fourth edition](https://www.amazon.in/Macroeconomics-N-Gregory-Mankiw/dp/9386668424/ref=asc_df_9386668424/?tag=googleshopmob-21&linkCode=df0&hvadid=397043648623&hvpos=&hvnetw=g&hvrand=6060487756944336755&hvpone=&hvptwo=&hvqmt=&hvdev=m&hvdvcmdl=&hvlocint=&hvlocphy=9300972&hvtargid=pla-836688003779&psc=1&ext_vrnc=hi).

What are the differences between the two editions? Specifically, are there new topics that have been added (if so, how important are they for a first introduction to economics?), major additions to existing topics, or topics that have been removed entirely?

My background is that I am currently reading Hal A. Varian's *Intermediate Microeconomics: A Modern Approach* and working through his *Workouts in Intermediate Microeconomics*.

Comment: Definitely don't use this: https://libgen.lc/

Comment: Your first link will show the contents of the 10th edition.  Compare that to the contents of your 4th edition and see if you care.  I would guess that if the earlier version covers for example the world financial crisis of 2007-2008, then you might decide that there is not a big enough difference to justify paying for a new version.